# How to add attachment button in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, desktop-application

I've developed a small ticketing system on excel VBA
The Save button will take all data from textboxes and radio button and add it to the row number 7 (in this case)
But when I press upload I can't add the link to the label of attachments

How to add link to the attachment label using (upload file ) button
And also save the Link value stored in upload file button to use it later in clear button and save button?

I'm confused to work with private sub and private dim variables.
I'm newbie in VBA please help

[System of Ticketing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GbWB.png)

**The Upload button**

```
Public Sub btnAttachment_Click()

'To upload file link format is png, jpeg, PDF or All files'

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim LinksList As Range
Dim lastRowLink As Long
Dim LinkAttached As Long

Set wks = ActiveSheet

Set LinksList = Range("N1")


'declare last row to insert link to
lastRowLink = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Tickets").Range("A:A"))
 Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 11).Value = LinkAttached
 

    ChDrive "C:\"
    ChDir "C:\"
    Filt = "PNG Files(*.png),*.png ," & _
            "Jpeg Files(*.jpeg),*.jpg ," & _
            "PDF Files (*.pdf),*.pdf ," & _
            "All Files (*.*),*.*"
    FilterIndex = 1
    Title = "Select a File to Hyperlink"
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (FileFilter:=Filt, _
         FilterIndex:=FilterIndex, _
         Title:=Title)

    If Filename <> False Then
       wks.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=LinksList, _
       Address:=Filename, _
        TextToDisplay:=Filename
    Else
        MsgBox "No file was selected.", vbCritical, "Loading Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

**The Save button code**

```
Public Sub BtnSave_Click()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim openOn As Date
   
    
    'Declare openBy to date Now function'
    openOn = Now()
    'set format function on time var'
    openTimeAmPM = Format(openOn, "m.d.yy h:mm AM/PM")
    'if no all information required inserted, show error'
    If SieraForum.txtTicketName.Value = "" Or (SieraForum.ErrorOption = False And SieraForum.OrderOption = False) Or SieraForum.CombLocation.Value = "" Or SieraForum.CombOpenBy.Value = "" Or SieraForum.CombTicketStatus.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox " Please fill All information required (Ticket Name, Severity, Location, OpenBy)"

    Else
    lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Tickets").Range("A:A"))
    
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = lastRow
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = SieraForum.txtTicketName.Value
    
    If SieraForum.ErrorOption = True Then
     Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = "Error"
    Else
     Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = "Order"
    End If
       
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = SieraForum.CombSeverity.Value
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = SieraForum.CombLocation.Value
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 6).Value = SieraForum.txtTicketDetails.Value
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = SieraForum.CombOpenBy.Value
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 8).Value = SieraForum.CombCloseBy.Value
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 9).Value = SieraForum.CombTicketStatus.Value
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 10).Value = openTimeAmPM
    
    'Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 13).Value =
    
    
    'Display new ticket number on the label'
    lbTicketNumVal.Caption = lastRow
   End If
  
  'to clear data after pressing Save button'
  
'Clear the data from the form'
SieraForum.txtTicketName.Value = ""
SieraForum.ErrorOption = False
SieraForum.OrderOption = False
SieraForum.CombSeverity = ""
SieraForum.CombLocation = ""
SieraForum.txtTicketDetails = ""
SieraForum.CombOpenBy = ""
SieraForum.CombCloseBy = ""
SieraForum.CombTicketStatus = ""
lbTicketNumVal.Caption = lastRow + 1
   
    
'to save excel sheet editing'
ActiveWorkbook.Save

     
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to update the label text on the form?

Comment: No, I have tickets for each time the user add a ticket it will submitted into a new row,
the upload key should add the link of attached file in the same row ticket on cell M and each time will add the link into the same row of the ticket number

Comment: basically I need the same sub of Save button to be on Upload button in term of link value

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the ticker row will already exist in the sheet. For the upload, you just need to update the row with the link filename. There can also be multiple links.

At the bottom of `btnAttachment_Click()`, add this code:

```
rw = SieraForum.lbTicketNumVal.Caption   ' ticket number label
' append filename to cell value
Sheets("Tickets").Cells(rw, 13).Value = Sheets("Tickets").Cells(rw, 13).Value & vbcrlf & Filename
```

It assumes column 13 (M) is the link column you want to update. It gets the row number from the ticket label.

Comment: No, the row not exist, it should open a new row,

Comment: Second thing , the link added as a string (long) I need it hyperlink, see the example below the variable LinksList  it return the hyper link but I failed to write it into the same new row 

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim LinksList As Range
    Dim lastRowLink As Long
    Dim LinkAttached As Variant
    
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    
    Set LinksList = Range("N1")